# Greoupby With Max() condition SQL Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions, alation

I need to groupby a function and return only rows that have max value for each variable that I choose.
In this case the variables are user_id, and task.

My input is shown in the table below:

```
user_id task    mx
123456  expecd  4.85
789101  Packing 3.17
123456  Packing 1.50
789101  receiv  0.08
```

And i apply the query below.

```
select user_id, task, max(time_sum) as mx
from process
group by user_id,task) with data on commit preserve rows;
```

But it isn’t working to get my target that is the table below.

```
user_id task    mx
123456  expecd  4.85
789101  Packing 3.17
```

Could you please guide me to get a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the row with the greatest `mx` for each `user_id`.

In Teradata, you can use `row_number()` and `qualify` to solve this greatest-n-per-group problem.

```
select t.*
from mytable t
qualify row_number() over(partition by user_id order by mx desc) = 1
```